# creating individual Variables in pyomo with different length

Tags: pyomo, binary-variable

I am new to pyomo and I do have some smaller (or bigger) problems and hope someone can help me.  How can you create this variable in pyomo? I wanted to create it with pyo.Varlist() in which I pass every other variable with index, but that did not work.

$x_j \in \{0,1\}^{\vert D_j \vert}$

model.J = pyo.Set($[1, ..., n]$), $j \in [1, ... ,n]$ and $\vert D_j\vert \in [1, ...,m]$

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. If the following answer is not what you are looking for, would you explain more about the `different length` of the variables?

Comment: for each $j$ the $\vert D_j \vert$ can be different. The $D_j$ stands for the target location of the job $j$.
Ok maybe I have to explain a litte bit more:

Comment: I am working on a Problem for logistics. I have $J = \{ 1, ... , n\}$ transportorders and each transportorder has different numbers of target locations, thats the $\vert D_j \vert$. I try to model the problem of the sequence of the transportorders, as well as the assigment problem, because the transports just restricts the target locations. I have to determine the best target location for that restriction.
Some transportorders can go to the same restriction and therefore the sequence is essentiel for the assigment. I hope this explains all a litte bit better.

Comment: If I understand your issue, you do not need to imply any filtering on the definitions of the variables, just define an array or dictionary that contains the value of the subset, $|D_{j}|$, and apply that as a filter on your desired constraint. e.g. define a dictionary of the form: subset = {1:(2,3), 2:(4,6), ...}. that keys are elements of the set $J$, and its values are the elements of $|D_{j}|$. Then over a loop on the constraint call this dictionary to implement what you want. I hope it will help.

Comment: I am new to pyomo and I didn't know that is possible to create a variable with dictionaries. I will try it with that example code below. I am sure I will soon need some more help. I was surprised how quickly I got help. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach that I would take.  Having both an indexed set `m.J_K` and its companion flat set will likely prove valuable in construction of constraints.

Here is another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996930/using-discontinuous-indices-for-pyomo-optimization/73997720#73997720).

##### Code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

Dj_len = {1: 3,
          2: 2,
          3: 5,
          4: 1}

m = pyo.ConcreteModel('example')

m.J = pyo.Set(initialize=Dj_len.keys())
m.K = pyo.Set(initialize=range(1, max(Dj_len.values()) + 1))

def J_K_init(m, j):
    return range(1, Dj_len[j]+1)
m.J_K = pyo.Set(m.J, initialize=J_K_init)
m.J_K_flat = pyo.Set(within = m.J * m.K, initialize=[(j, k) for j in m.J for k in m.J_K[j]])

m.x = pyo.Var(m.J_K_flat, domain=pyo.Binary)

m.pprint()
```

##### Output:

```
5 Set Declarations
    J : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    4 : {1, 2, 3, 4}
    J_K : Size=4, Index=J, Ordered=Insertion
        Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
          1 :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
          2 :     1 :    Any :    2 : {1, 2}
          3 :     1 :    Any :    5 : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
          4 :     1 :    Any :    1 : {1,}
    J_K_flat : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain          : Size : Members
        None :     2 : J_K_flat_domain :   11 : {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1)}
    J_K_flat_domain : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    J*K :   20 : {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)}
    K : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    5 : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=11, Index=J_K_flat
        Key    : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (1, 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (1, 2) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (1, 3) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (2, 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (2, 2) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (3, 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (3, 2) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (3, 3) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (3, 4) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (3, 5) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
        (4, 1) :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary

6 Declarations: J K J_K J_K_flat_domain J_K_flat x
```